# File Always Exist Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch which check the existence of a file.  Please see code below..

```
  @ECHO OFF

  REM Clear screen before executing other commands 
  CLS 

  SET WebConfig=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC\Web.Config
  SET CodeLocation=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC\*.*


  IF NOT EXIST %WebConfig% GOTO WebError

  :WebError
     ECHO Web.Config File doesn't Exist...
     pause
     GOTO:EOF

  ECHO Working..
```

When executing the batch file, i always receive an error file doesn't exist.. Even though the file exist in the define folder..

Can you guys help me..? Hope to hear from you soon..

Thanks,

Nestea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at this section of code:

```
IF NOT EXIST %WebConfig% GOTO WebError
:WebError
```

Now what happens when the file exists? Don't answer, it's rhetorical :-)

It drops through to the next line which is, wait for it, the error message section.

Try this instead, it skips over the error message section when the `if` statement doesn't jump:

```
    if not exist %WebConfig% goto WebError
    goto WebOkay
:WebError
    echo Web.Config File doesn't exist.
    pause
    goto :EOF
:WebOkay
    echo Working.
```

It can also be further simplified to:

```
    if exist %WebConfig% goto WebOkay
    echo Web.Config File doesn't exist.
    pause
    goto :EOF
:WebOkay
    echo Working.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange your batch file somewhat, so that it has the right flow of execution.

You need to keep going unless the file does NOT exist, in which case you jump out. See the `REM` statements marked with `***` below:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Clear screen before executing other commands 
CLS 

SET WebConfig=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC\Web.Config
SET CodeLocation=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC\*.*

REM *** If the web config file doesn't exist, skip the rest
REM *** of the batch file and show an error. Otherwise, keep
REM *** going.
IF NOT EXIST %WebConfig% GOTO WebError

ECHO Working... 
REM *** Other "working" stuff here, then jump past WebError block
GOTO Eof

:WebError
ECHO Web.Config File doesn't Exist...
pause

:EOF
REM Do whatever else here
```