# exist file batch file

Tags: batch-file

I try in my batch file to verify if a file exist on the machine.

I use the following but it failed:

```
if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Mcafee"(
pause
)
```

Do you know why?

Comment: How does it fail? Does it not pause? Does it crash? Give an error?  Are you checking for a file or a folder?

Comment: it crash,I checking folder but also it happen if I checking file

Comment: If you checking solution for her look might be with good answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694720/file-always-exist-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

You have no space between your directory path and the opening bracket of the `if` statement, which will make it see the bracket as part of the filename.

Try using

```
if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Mcafee" (
pause
)
```

instead which should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for parenthesis just do

if exist C:\users\administrator\desktop\McAffee pause

also if you are attempting to open a shortcut to mcaffe from a batch it will not work because it cant change the directory of the batch file.